# Stepwise subsetting of a list in Python

Tags: python

My current solution looks like:

```
import numpy as np

chunksize = 10
l = list(np.arange(0,99))

while len(l) > chunksize:
    l_subset = l
    l_subset = l_subset[0:chunksize]
    l.pop(0)
    print(l_subset)
```

This doesn't look like a very efficient solution, since .pop requires traversing the list. What are fast ways to do that?

Comment: Can you try and explain what it is you are trying to do? BTW, the line `l_subset = l` is unnecessary and could just be `l_subset = l[0:chunksize]`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Any why do you first copy `l` to `l_subset` and then immediately replace it with a subset instead of `l_subset = l[0:chunksize]`?

Comment: Isn't your loop effectively the same as just doing `l[-chunksize:]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
del l[0]
```

This will only remove the item at index zero without returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy is the fastest solution I've found:

```
import numpy as np
import time
chunksize = 10
arr = np.arange(0,99999)
l = list(arr)

start = time.time()
while len(l) > chunksize:
    l_subset = l
    l_subset = l_subset[0:chunksize]
    l.pop(0)
runTime = time.time()-start
print(runTime) #0.8397529125213623s

l = list(arr)
start = time.time()
while len(l) > chunksize:
    l_subset = l
    l_subset = l_subset[0:chunksize]
    del l[0]
 runTime = time.time()-start
 print(runTime) #0.879807710647583s

 start = time.time()
 lower = 0
 upper = chunksize
 n_subset = int(len(arr)/chunksize)
 for i in range(n_subset):
     arr[lower:upper]
     lower = lower + 1
     upper = upper + 1
runTime = time.time()-start
print(runTime) # 0.002997159957885742s
```